# cronjob setting through command prompt

Tags: linux, cron, command

I have set cronjob for a linux server through cpanel and its working properly. But now I have a linux server which has no cpanel. So for this cpanel, I have to set the cronjob, but without cpanel how to do that please instruct me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi check this link here step by step explan how you can set cron using comman prompt. Its a very gud tutorial for me .. http://phpsollutions.blogspot.in/2014/02/set-up-cron-job-using-command-prompt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add your crontab to the /etc/cron.d/ directory, eg:

Write this line of text to a file (you can name that file anything you like) and save it to `/etc/cron.d/` :

`0 */4 * * * root /path/to/script.sh`

Would execute `script.sh` as `root` every 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e` from the command line will allow you to edit your user's cron tab.

Syntax of that file is described in the file and online